# Step and repeat for offset path - Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, blending-objects

In Adobe Illustrator, is there a workaround to easily repeat the process of offsetting a path? Just as you can input the number of desired steps using the blend tool, is there a similar option for the offset path command? I am also wondering why it isn’t possible to constrain proportions when using the blend tool with irregular shapes…

A similar thread on Adobe Forums can be found [here](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1305191?tstart=0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an action (Window -> Actions) for this.

1. Create New Action and name it
2. Select shape and go to Object -> Path -> Offset Path and input the amount you want.
3. Stop the action

Now just hit the play button to re-use that offset.

Comment: Thank you! This is probably the best solution. I still think that having to set up an action to achieve this result is ridiculous.

Comment: @luimeme you could probably create a script that functions like step and repeat from InDesign (inputting how many repeats, width, and height) but I am not sure how to create that.

Comment: This is a really good way to do it, but also you can give`Offset path` a shortcut. Since the window keeps the last inserted value, it's about as fast to make multiple offsets quickly this way, compared to an Action with a single offset. If I wanted to add like 20+ offsets to multiple objects, I might record the action by using the shortcut.

Comment: You could probably just offset your path to the largest copy and use the blend tool to define the steps in between. That way you avoid creating an action.