# Custom shapes Russian Doll

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes

I am interested in creating something like the following with custom shapes. I am used to creating vector shape layers - but I am not sure how to create this Russian doll concept properly where the dimensions/angles are retained for a pure clean psd.

[image]

when I create a custom shape -- and start to try and mimic this -- the angles change.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm posting this answer mostly to demonstrate that Lucian is actually correct here (already gave him a +1)... and partly because I'm dying to try out my new KBD button.

Anyhow – I would just differ a tiny bit from what he said though (in this case). I'm going to start with the path just outside of the bottle first:

[image: Path number 1]

- I used the pen tool (holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key for the straight sections) and created the path with a 20px stroke and no fill

Once that's out of the way, this process can be done "manually" but depending on the size and number of strokes you're going to add this can take and will forever... So why not create an action?

- Go to Window > Actions and click on the 'Create New Action' button at the bottom of the panel, then hit the 'Record' button (add function key if you wish):

[image: Actions Panel]

- Go to Object > Path > Offset Path and (clearing the field) enter 39px:

[image: One path, offset]

This offsets the path outward by 40-1px (so that the gaps are slightly narrower than the strokes) and duplicates it in one step...

- Click 'Stop' in the Actions Panel.

Sit back in your easy chair and hit the 'Play' button (in this case) 13 times to repeat the process:

[image: The ease of automation]

- Daring to be different now select the original stroke (the innermost one) and go to Object > Path > Offset Path one last time
- This time clear the field and enter a negative value of -29, then change the Joins from 'Miter' to 'Round' and click 'OK'
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to swap your fill and stroke
- Finally press the <kbd>A</kbd> key to activate the Direct Selection Tool, then go to the top of the UI and click on 'Corners'. Choose 'Round' and enter 10 or 12px:

[image: Corner rounding]

The end result IMO leaves little doubt that Illustrator was the program and that this was almost certainly the general method used to create the original graphic.

[image: DRUNKMAKER]

Hope this makes things clearer for you... Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have access to Illustrator, with your original bottle shape selected, go to 'Object → Path → Offset Path' and experiment with the 'Offset' value. Every time you run this it adds a larger copy of your original shape, then replicate this with the same 'Offset' value multiple times to add more copies.

See this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ejaJYL3qx_g) and also [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/68143/step-and-repeat-for-offset-path-illustrator) question on how to automate this.

Comment: Ah I only got the licence for the photoshop cc

Comment: Not sure you can do that in PS. This is what AI was created - to add vector features beyond the basic PS tools.

Comment: Cheers man - yeah I had a similar issue with trying to create step ladder text

Comment: Edited my answer and added a video link which shows you how its done.

Comment: This ought to be the accepted answer!

Comment: It was approved, then the OP marked the other answer. Maybe it worked somehow with a blend, and i was tempted to suggest a blend initially, but a blend is not ideal as it can _change the angles_ as the OP mentioned. The Offset Path solution is better for this imho.

Answer (score 1):

You are misguided in thinking that these are somehow "concentric" shapes around the bottle shape (except perhaps at the top). Everything else is a regular grid, with translations and rotations. The part where you aren't too successful is just a diagonal grid:

- Generate a vertical grid on a transparent layer
- Duplicate and rotate by 40% on another layer
- Make an oblique rectangle selection, the slant being the bisector of both grids (blue dots, below)
- With that selection delete the vertical grid
- Invert the selection and delete the oblique grid

[image]

Comment: Yeah but its not part of the entire entity - what about the curved top -- the method Lucian mentioned wouldn't fix this?

Comment: Its not just at the top - but also at the bottom too

Comment: So this is the thing --- if you have to do some concentric shape at the top and the bottom - would it be applicable to also do the same with this diagonal grid bit -- cause what if you want to change the colours from red and white -- to blue and green? etc..

Comment: @TheOldCounty Certainly not, with these inwards corners.

Comment: @TheOldCounty *cause what if you want to change the colours from red and white -- to blue and green? etc.. –* You just render the grid with a different color, or am I missing something?

Comment: yeah but the top and bottom parts - the concentric parts ... why would these be ignored/treated as different elements.

Comment: Because they are different elements :)

Answer (score 1):

The image is almost certainly created in vector image editing software such as Adobe Illustrator.

It's a Blend between two outlines

Example of a Blend in Illustrator

[image: Example of a Blend in Illustrator]

Comment: I will try and get at trial version of Illustrator going to get it up - yeah I figured as much -- would you be willing to send me some of these illustrator demos you cooked up?

Comment: Sure, here's the AI file. http://www.filedropper.com/blend

Comment: @BillyKerr How did you create the two paths used in your blend (particularly the outermost one)?

Comment: @BANG without knowing i would guess using offset becase thats the way it should be done.

Comment: @BANG The outermost one is simply a copy of the inner one which I simply adjusted by moving the anchors. The nice thing about a blend is that it's a live effect, you can continue to edit the paths after applying the blend. Agree however after seeing your answer that an offset is the best answer if the OP wants to match the effect exactly.

Comment: Wvy not simply offset?

Comment: @joojaa - sure, why not, but there are many ways to skin a cat. I often prefer to make manual adjustments to everything, probably due to the fact I began using vector image editing software (Aldus Freehand actually) long before it had any fancy features.

Comment: @BillyKerr its less work and more accurate. I doubt that there ever existed a vector software that didnt have offset for very long atleast. Since doing thinner than pixel lines needs offset. So literally the second feature you implement.

Comment: Err sorry thicker than a pixel mostly but even for thinner ones.